# raw depth data to text kinect v1.0 C#

Tags: c#, text, kinect, depth

I've been searching the internet and I haven't had any luck. I'm using an Xbox Kinect with the Kinect SDK v1.0. I want to take the raw depth data and convert it into a text document so I can use the depth data. I found something on this site but it was for the Beta2 and I need to use v1.0. Any help is appreciated but I am new to coding so sample code would be best.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace DepthTextStream
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    const float MaxDepthDistance = 4095; // max value returned
    const float MinDepthDistance = 850; // min value returned
    const float MaxDepthDistanceOffset = MaxDepthDistance - MinDepthDistance;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        kinectSensorChooser1.KinectSensorChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(kinectSensorChooser1_KinectSensorChanged);

    }

    void kinectSensorChooser1_KinectSensorChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var oldSensor = (KinectSensor)e.OldValue;

        //stop the old sensor
        if (oldSensor != null)
        {
            oldSensor.Stop();
            oldSensor.AudioSource.Stop();
        }

        //get the new sensor
        var newSensor = (KinectSensor)e.NewValue;
        if (newSensor == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //turn on features that you need
        newSensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution320x240Fps30);
        newSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(); 

        //sign up for events if you want to get at API directly
        newSensor.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(newSensor_AllFramesReady);


        try
        {
            newSensor.Start();
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
            //this happens if another app is using the Kinect
            kinectSensorChooser1.AppConflictOccurred();
        }
    }

    void newSensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        short[] depthData;

        using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame()) //create a new frame every time one is ready
    {
    //assign a value to depthData
    depthData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
    } 

    }


    private void SaveDepthData(short[] depthData)
    {
        //initialize a StreamWriter
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:/Example.txt");

        //search the depth data and add it to the file
        for (int i = 0; i < depthData.Length; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(depthData[i] + "\n"); //\n for a new line
        }

        //dispose of sw
        sw.Close();
        SaveDepthData(depthData);
    }      

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        StopKinect(kinectSensorChooser1.Kinect); 
    }

    private void StopKinect(KinectSensor sensor)
    {
        if (sensor != null)
        {
            if (sensor.IsRunning)
            {
                //stop sensor 
                sensor.Stop();

                //stop audio if not null
                if (sensor.AudioSource != null)
                {
                    sensor.AudioSource.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Version 1.0? Why not 1.5.0.1?

Comment: Why would you need to add it to a text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty simple using version 1.5.0.1, which is **practically** the same as version 1.0 and will work on it. All you need to complete this is A)a `short[]` to hold the depth data B)a `DepthImageFrame` to move the data to the array, and C)A `StreamWriter` to save the data.

Add a `short[]` to store your depth data, and inside of your `DepthFrameReadyEventArgs` (or `AllFramesReadyEventArgs`) you "use" a `DepthImageFrame` by doing:

```
 short[] depthData;

 ...

 using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame(()) //create a new frame every time one is ready
 {
       //assign a value to depthData
       depthData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
 }
```

Then you can add the depth from each frame to `depthData` using `DepthImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo`

```
 using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame(()) //create a new frame every time one is ready
 {
       //assign a value to depthData
       depthData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];

       //add raw depth data to depthData
       depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(depthData);
 }
```

Then we can write a method to save our data using a `StreamWriter`.

```
 private void SaveDepthData(short[] depthData)
 {
       //initialize a StreamWriter
       StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:/Example.txt");

       //search the depth data and add it to the file
       for (int i = 0; i < depthData.Length; i++)
       {
            sw.WriteLine(depthData[i] + "\n"); //\n for a new line
       }

       //dispose of sw
       sw.Close();
 }      

 ...

 SaveDepthData(depthData);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I won't be able to help for the next few days as I will be camping:)

Comment: @Outlaw_Lemur I took my previous code, most of which I got from a tutorial, and edited it and added what you gave me. I get an error when i add the streamwriter. Is there a reference I need to add? Also where is what i'm saving being sent. To the (@"C:/Example.txt");?

Comment: Add "using System.IO;" to the top for StreamWriter.  And yes, in his example all data would save to C:/Example.txt

Comment: When I added everything I get no errors but when I run it there is a NullReferenceException unhandled. I'll post my code below. Can anyone tell me where my error is?