# Access Kinect Depth Data with Pykinect

Tags: python, kinect, pykinect

I'm currently working on a project where I need to access and process depth data using the PyKinect library.

What I want to do is to define a depth threshold where I'll do some image segmentation, but since I'm new to PyKinect and I still don't know quite well where to look for resources, I don't know how to access that data and get the values.

I've tried to use the freenect library also, but I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone tell me how to do that or redirect me to some kind of documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just created a [snippet on my BitBucket account](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/VitoGentile/Eoze) to visualize a depth image with PyKinect and Pygame. Here is the code:

```
import thread
import pygame
from pykinect import nui

DEPTH_WINSIZE = 320,240

screen_lock = thread.allocate()
screen = None

tmp_s = pygame.Surface(DEPTH_WINSIZE, 0, 16)


def depth_frame_ready(frame):
    with screen_lock:
        frame.image.copy_bits(tmp_s._pixels_address)
        arr2d = (pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(tmp_s) >> 7) & 255
        pygame.surfarray.blit_array(screen, arr2d)

        pygame.display.update()


def main():
    """Initialize and run the game."""
    pygame.init()

    # Initialize PyGame
    global screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DEPTH_WINSIZE, 0, 8)
    screen.set_palette(tuple([(i, i, i) for i in range(256)]))
    pygame.display.set_caption('PyKinect Depth Map Example')

    with nui.Runtime() as kinect:
        kinect.depth_frame_ready += depth_frame_ready   
        kinect.depth_stream.open(nui.ImageStreamType.Depth, 2, nui.ImageResolution.Resolution320x240, nui.ImageType.Depth)

        # Main game loop
        while True:
            event = pygame.event.wait()

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT**: The above code shows how to convert depth data to an 8-bit representation (so that they can be easily drawn as a grayscale image). But if you want to use actual depth data, you need to know how they are structured.

Using the Microsoft Kinect SDK (on which PyKinect is based), a single depth pixel is composed by 16 bits. The 3 less significative ones represent the player index, while I have not well understood the meaning of the most significative one... But let's say that we need to remove the last 3 bits and the first one. For instance, this is an example of what you need to do for each pixel (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587178/how-to-convert-kinect-raw-depth-info-to-meters-in-matlab)):

```
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 - 16 bits number
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1       - 13 bits number
  1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1       - 12 bits number
```

The above operation (removing the last 3 bits and the first one) can be implemented with two bitwise operation on the `arr2d` array. Because it is a NumPy array, you can proceed as follows:

```
def depth_frame_ready(frame):
    frame.image.copy_bits(tmp_s._pixels_address)

    arr2d = (pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(tmp_s) >> 3) & 4095
    # arr2d[x,y] is the actual depth measured in mm at (x,y)
```

Then, you can have the need to display this data, so you will probably need an 8-bit representation. To get it:

```
arr2d >>= 4
```

Comment: What I want to do, is to set a layer between depths to capture only my extended hand for example, and do some image processing on it, not so much getting the depth map.
I wanted to know and understand how to get the actual values from the depth map.

Comment: I have just edited my answer. In the first solution I have processed bits in order to display them as a grayscale image. If you have the necessity to get the actual depth data, simply use the second code snippet that I have just added. If you then need to display depth data after some processing, simply execute the last shift (`arr2d >>= 4`) before displaying them: this last operation will convert your processed depth map in a 8-bit grayscale image.

Comment: Thank you, that will do for what I'm trying to do, I didn't knew how to work  an interpret the depth map and was guessing there was a function from PyKinect that filtered any unwanted depth data given a threshold or something similar I could use.